# Scaling a Java based tree

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, scalability

I wrote a tree in Java that supports multiple children nodes and edges. I haven't had to worry about scaling this application up until now. The use case now requires that there be 100 or more instances of the tree to be searched and maintained.

I've done very minimal research in this domain. The first thing that comes to mind is Spark. How I understand it though, is that Spark batches windows of events - almost removing the "in stream" aspect. Time is very critical here.

So I was thinking of taking advantage of Hadoop's file system. Indexing the tree across the cluster and using MapReduce to do maintenance.

I don't mind a good read. If there is any articles, tutorials, and or recommendations, that would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

`Hadoop` and `Spark` are both distributed processing systems. `Spark` was designed to override the drawbacks of `Hadoop` system.

`Hadoop` has two parts, a storage system called `hdfs` and a processing algorithm called `map-reduce`. `Spark` was developed analyzing drawbacks in `map-reduce`. Hence `RDD` (resilient distributed datasets) was introduced in `spark` for in memory distributed processing. More information can be found in [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/programming-guide.html) and [Jacek](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/)

We can use the powerful hadoop filesystem with `Spark` processing as well.

If you choose `spark`, you would learn functional programming with `scala` or `python` or `R`. `Hadoop` is dependent on `map-reduce` algorithm which is a bit complex to be followed.

And there are `api`s for [Tree in scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.7/scala/collection/immutable/Tree.html) and there are works uderway too for example [this](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/datastructures/Tree.scala) and [this](https://github.com/TheDom/functional-programming-in-scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/dominikgruber/fpinscala/chapter03/Tree.scala)

I hope this is helpful.